# MacOS Change menubar Icon using swift 4

Tags: swift, swift4, macos-mojave

With the new Dark mode in MacOS Mojave I would like to change the menubar icon of my app. In default, it is a white black bear and rather than just inverting the colors I would like to use an icon of a snoozing bear.

I have all my code that sets up the menubar icon in `AppDelegate` in `applicationDidFinishLaunching`. So my question is: Is there a way to check if the dark mode was activated and then change the icon using swift 4?

I tried:

```
var inDarkMode: Bool {
  let mode = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "AppleInterfaceStyle")
  return mode == "Dark"
}
```

and then an if statement around

```
button.image = NSImage(named: NSImage.Name(rawValue: "StatusBarButtonImage"))
```

but because the code is in `applicationDidFinishLaunching` this will only check once.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: What you need is to customize your image assets for different appearances. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/images_and_pdf/providing_images_for_different_appearances

Answer (score 1):

As pointed to by Leo in the comments, [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/images_and_pdf/providing_images_for_different_appearances) explain the process clearly:

1. open your asset catalog and add a new image asset.
2. in the right side menu, click on the dropdown at *Appearances*:

[image]

It should be *Any* by default, change it to *Any, Dark*, or *Any, Light, Dark* to customize the icons you want to use for each case.