# macOS Mojave: Change app icon to match Dark/Light Mode

Tags: macos-mojave, macos-darkmode

Is there a way to change my app icon dynamically when switching between Dark/Light Mode in macOS Mojave?

I wish to change the icon appearance to appear appropriately in system alerts and notifications.

Comment: The answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52768874/macos-change-menubar-icon-using-swift-4 may be of some use to you. The answer provided this link which has a lot of information on setting icons for different modes: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/images_and_pdf/providing_images_for_different_appearances

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your best bet is to handle the icon change yourself: listen to appearance change notifications, and update the icon accordingly.

To set the Dock icon:

- The easiest way is to assign a `NSImage` to [`NSApp.applicationIconImage`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplication/1428744-applicationiconimage). However, this only works when the app is running, and the change is cleared when the app quits.
- A more reliable way, that keeps working when the app is not running, is to use a [dock tile plugin](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsdocktileplugin). The implementation is more involved, however, as you need to create and configure an additional target.